# Getting the SHA1 block from GNAT.SHA1

Tags: sha1, ada, gnat

I am using `GNAT.SHA1` to create a `SHA1` hash of a string in `Ada`. My code base is small, so I'd like to avoid importing any libraries to the project that aren't provided by my compiler, hence I'm using `GNAT.SHA1`. As far as I'm aware, the only "public" methods for retrieving the hash is in String form via the `Digest` function. I would like to instead get the 160-bit block that is the `H` member of the `Context` type. Unfortunately, the `Context` record is private. Is there any way I can get at it? Or is their an alternative method provided by `GNAT` or the Ada standard library?

Comment: Looking at the implementation (one advantage of having the source!), it seems that `Digest (C : Context)` does a great deal more than converting the bits in `C` to hex! so unless you were planning to re-do that; I’d have thought your best bet would be what @Keith Thompson suggests.

Comment: I think @Keith Thompson's suggestion is the best answer to my specific question. Ultimately, I decided to download John Halleck's SHA1 [implementation](http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/ada/sha/); just 3 source files to add to my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any direct way to get the 160-bit block, but of course you can compute it from the hexadecimal string.

Here's an example I just threw together.  (Granted, extracting 32-bit integers by adding `"16#"` and `"#"` to the hex substring may not be the most elegant solution.

```
with GNAT.SHA1;
with Interfaces;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure SHA1_Demo is
    C: GNAT.SHA1.Context;
    package U32_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Modular_IO(Interfaces.Unsigned_32);
    use U32_IO;
begin
    GNAT.SHA1.Update(C, "hello");
    declare
        SHA1: constant String := GNAT.SHA1.Digest(C);
        H: array(0..4) of Interfaces.Unsigned_32;
    begin
        Put_Line("SHA1(""hello"") = " & GNAT.SHA1.Digest(C));
        for I in Integer range 0 .. 4 loop
            H(I) := Interfaces.Unsigned_32'Value
                        ("16#" & SHA1(I*8+1 .. I*8+8) & "#");
            Put("H(");
            Put(I, Width => 0);
            Put(") = ");
            Put(H(I), Base => 16);
            New_Line;
        end loop;
    end;
end SHA1_Demo;
```

The output is:

```
SHA1("hello") = aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d
H(0) = 16#AAF4C61D#
H(1) = 16#DCC5E8A2#
H(2) = 16#DABEDE0F#
H(3) = 16#3B482CD9#
H(4) = 16#AEA9434D#
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. I'm just not happy with GNAT converting the binary array to a hex string, and the converting back again in my code. I downloaded a GPL-licensed SHA1 implementation which returns a digest as a 5x32-bit-integer array.

Comment: GNAT's implementation is GPL; you could rename it and modify it to make `H` visible.  You might also consider contacting the GNAT folks and asking them to make `H` visible in future releases.

Comment: GOod idea! I didn't think of that. It never really occurs that we can just change the compiler libraries.